# Keep only two part on element within a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for a commande in python in order to only keep within a list the `3 first letters` between `content_content > con_con`
here is an example:

```
list_exp=["Babylona_expetiendra","Ocracylus_machabrus","Ojeris_multifasciatus"]

list_exp=["Bab_exp","Ocr_mac","Oje_mul"]
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thank you for your help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list-comprehension:

```
['_'.join(map(lambda x: x[:3], x.split('_'))) for x in list_exp]
```

**Code**:

```
list_exp=["Babylona_expetiendra","Ocracylus_machabrus","Ojeris_multifasciatus"]

print(['_'.join(map(lambda x: x[:3], x.split('_'))) for x in list_exp])
# ['Bab_exp', 'Ocr_mac', 'Oje_mul']
```

Comment: Could you please explain how you came up with this list comprehension! I want to start learning list-comprehension to solve complex problems like these @austin

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, comprehension takes each element splits on `'_'` and with `map` gets first three chars out of each split and a final `join` brings the expected output. What you do in normal way is summed up. Nothing fancy.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

> Before running all these, just have a quick look at the use of `list comprehension` & `join()`, `split()` methods defined on strings.

```
>>> list_exp = ["Babylona_expetiendra","Ocracylus_machabrus","Ojeris_multifasciatus"]
>>> 
>>> output = ['_'.join([part[:3] for part in name.split("_")]) for name in list_exp]
>>> output
['Bab_exp', 'Ocr_mac', 'Oje_mul']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you :) it helped a lot

Comment: It is my pleasure. Thank you @chippycentra.

Answer (score 1):

```
[
    *map(
        lambda strip:'_'.join([st[:3] for st in strip]),
        [
            *map(
                lambda s:s.split('_'),
                ["Babylona_expetiendra","Ocracylus_machabrus","Ojeris_multifasciatus"]
            )
        ]
    )
]
```

mess explanation:

First we are splitting every string in list by '_' gigving us

```
[['Babylona', 'expetiendra'], ['Ocracylus', 'machabrus'], ['Ojeris', 'multifasciatus']]
```

Then we are getting first 3 letters using [:3] for every string inside new lists

Finnaly joining again with '_'.join()

```
['Bab_exp', 'Ocr_mac', 'Oje_mul']
```

This example using [map](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#map) [unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters/36908#36908) and [lamdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.